EF Power Tools - generating customization
I use EF Power Tools for generation DBContext and Entities with some modifications via CodeTemplates (Handlebars template).
Database context is generated to DataContext folder, data model to Entitity folder and I need to generate repositories to Repository folder. For repository class is needed the same data as EF Power Tools needs for generating entity class.
So, my idea is that i should generate repositories with EF model at same time, but i need generate this classes with different namespace and to different folder.
Is somehow possible modify scaffolding to generate new files to different folder?

Yes, it is possible to do this, if you use multiple T4 template sets, as described in the product wiki: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering#customize-code-using-t4-templates

Is it possible for you to add a sample efpt.config.json that uses multiple t4 templates? I modified the "T4TemplatePath": "..//folder//" and hosted four t4 templates in the folder, but the tool is not generating based on the t4 files. FYI, I customized the output path "OutputPath": "EntitiesGenerated" too.

@JeeShenLee Please create an issue in GitHub will more details
